# Nifi ExecuteScript / tail a file

Tags: python, apache-nifi, jython

I would like to tail logs files. (Unfortunately, in Nifi, the processor TailFile do not do what I want as the state seems to be lost if the tailed file is erased).

Thus I would like to but a similar processor with the ExecuteScript Command (Jython/python).
My main issue is to efficiently tail the file in Python within the Nifi Jython package.

```
> from org.apache.nifi.components.state import Scope from
> org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils from java.nio.charset import
> StandardCharsets from java.io import BufferedReader, InputStreamReader
> from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback
> 
> # Define a subclass of StreamCallback for use in session.write() class PyStreamCallback(StreamCallback):   def __init__(self, old_position,
> line_count):
>         self.__line_count = int(line_count)
>         self.__old_position = int(old_position)   def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
>     reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
>     try:
>         # Loop indefinitely
>         i = 0
>         tailled =[]
>         while True:
>             # Get the next line
>             line = reader.readLine()
>             # If there is no more content, break out of the loop
>             if line is None:
>                 break
>             else:
>                 i += 1
>             if i > self.__old_position:
>                 tailled.append(line)
>         outputs = '\n'.join(tailled)
>         outputStream.write(bytearray(outputs.encode('utf-8')))
> 
>     finally:
>         if reader is not None:
>             reader.close()
> 
> 
> # end class
> 
> 
> 
> stateManager = context.stateManager
> 
> stateMap = stateManager.getState(Scope.LOCAL) oldMap 
> stateManager.getState(Scope.LOCAL).toMap() flowFile = session.get()
> 
> if flowFile != None:
> 
>     unique_name = flowFile.getAttribute("absolute.path") + flowFile.getAttribute("filename")
>     line_count = flowFile.getAttribute("text.line.count")
>     new_map = {}
>     new_map.update(oldMap)
>     new_map.update({unique_name: line_count})
>     if stateMap.version == -1:
>         stateManager.setState(new_map, Scope.LOCAL)
>         old_position = stateMap.get(unique_name)
>         flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "old_position", old_position)
>         session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
>     else:
>         if stateMap.get(unique_name):
>             old_position = stateMap.get(unique_name)
>             flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "old_position", old_position)
>             flowFile = session.write(flowFile, PyStreamCallback(old_position, line_count))
>             session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
>             stateManager.replace(stateMap, new_map, Scope.LOCAL)
```

It works as it register the state (according to the path name: thus old_position from last reading) and read the lines of the FlowFiles (stream) in a BufferedReader. My FlowFiles could be quite huge and (XXX MB), thus this method is quite inefficient. "Output" variable, quickly become huge, and I am running out of Java Heap (1.5GB) for a small file (180MB)

> ```
>     # Loop indefinitely
>     i = 0
>     tailled =[]
>     while True:
>         # Get the next line
>         line = reader.readLine()
>         # If there is no more content, break out of the loop
>         if line is None:
>             break
>         else:
>             i += 1
>         if i > self.__old_position:
>             tailled.append(line)
>     outputs = '\n'.join(tailled)
> ```

I know the number of lines and where I need to start within the file (which is a Stream in my case), do you have an idea to fetch those last lines, in the best way?
I am open to switch from python.

I was in mind to add another processor to do the reading (ExecuteStreamCommand).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Don't store the lines in memory and write them all out at the end, instead you can write each line to the flowfile then repeat the loop, or create a bounded `tailled` buffer of X lines and write to the flowfile when you've reached X lines.

Comment: Following your advice, I wrote each line on the FlowFiles : outputStream.write(bytearray(outputs.encode('utf-8'))) 

It is working , but it's very slow (3min for 600MB), is there a way to "dump" a part of the flow file? I tried to mime SplitText code, but it's kind of complex to me right now.

Comment: the fastest way skip part of inputStream - use `inputStream.skip(bytesCount)` method. but in this case you have to remember bytes count instead of lines count.

Comment: That's perfect. I first UpdateAttribute to get FileSize visible to the ExecuteScript. Than I record the state of the flowfile, and use the skip method you just mentioned. Thank you for your help !